# python xlwings scraping data in put in excel sheet

Tags: excel, python-3.x, vba, xlwings

I m trying to have an code that permit to add harvest timesheets in excel automatically with a python code (which works fine).
So using xlwings, I add this code. It seems working as it takes one minute to work but nothing is imported in excel file.
Could some can help me ?

```
def timed():
    # id of the API
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + "XXXXXXXX",
        "Harvest-Account-ID": "XXXXX"
    }
    # define login infos
    headers = headers

    # define period for saving info about date of file update
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    Year = current_time.year
    Month = current_time.month
    actualMonth = "{:02d}".format(Month)  # mis au format 00 du mois
    day = current_time.day
    period = str(Year) + '-' + str(actualMonth) + '-' + str(day)

    # connection to harvest
    # premier jour de l'année
    begin_period = str(Year) + '-' + '01' + '-' + '01'
    url_address = "https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/time_entries?from=" + begin_period + "&per_page=100"

    response = requests.get(url_address, headers=headers)

    r = requests.get(url=url_address, headers=headers).json()

    # add info about number of pages
    try:
        total_pages = int(r['total_pages'])
    except:
        total_pages = 1


    timeentries = []
    # add data to pandas dataframe
    for page in range(0, total_pages):
        pages = page + 1
        url = "https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/time_entries?from=" + begin_period + "&page=" + str(
            pages) + "&per_page=100"
        response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
        test = response['time_entries']

        for tet in test:
            e = dict()
            e['id'] = tet['id']
            e['client'] = tet['client']['name']
            e['user'] = tet['user']['id']
            e['user_name'] = tet['user']['name']
            e['ID_project'] = tet['project']['id']
            e['ProjectName'] = tet['project']['name']
            e['hours'] = tet['hours']
            e['billable'] = tet['billable']
            e['Billed'] = tet['is_billed']
            e['spent_date'] = tet['spent_date']
            try:
                e['invoice'] = tet['invoice']['id']
            except:
                e['invoice'] = ''
            try:
                e['invoice_name'] = tet['invoice']['number']
            except:
                e['invoice_name'] = ''

            timeentries.append(e)

    # transfer to panda frame
    df = pd.DataFrame(timeentries)

@xw.func
@xw.ret(index=False, header=True, expand='table')
def ret_data_frame():
    return timed()
```

Objectif is to update all timesheet in an excel table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hin 
find my error.
in first def timed()
just add at the end:
return df